# returning row number only in vba

Tags: vba, excel

In excel vba is there way for getting only row number from range.

```
 set range=selection
```

Selection can be complete multiple row consecutive on or non consecutive or only cells it depend on user before running micro.
following line can give me row number but like this it will repeat the row for each cell but I want only row number only one time from any number of cells selected in row.

```
for each cell in range

    cell.row

next cell
```

or

```
for each range in SelectedRange.rows

    range.row

next range
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
 Dim Rng As Range, CL As Range

 Set Rng = Selection

 For Each CL In Application.Intersect(Rng.EntireRow, Rng.Worksheet.Columns(1))
  Debug.Print CL.Row
 Next
End Sub
```

Note: you can use any column 2,3,4.....

Comment: Thank you very much. I used your method.

Answer (score 1):

This will report each row only once:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim c As Collection
   Set c = New Collection
   On Error Resume Next
      For Each r In Selection
         c.Add r.Row, CStr(r.Row)
      Next r
   On Error GoTo 0

   msg = ""

   For i = 1 To c.Count
      msg = msg & vbCrLf & c.Item(i)
   Next i
   MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I used Fadi method to get row numbers and then save it in Collection.

Answer (score 0):

another one variant using dictionary:

```
Sub dural2()
   Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   Dim r As Range
   dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
   For Each r In Selection
       If Not dic.exists(r.Row) Then dic.Add r.Row, ""
   Next r
   MsgBox Join(dic.keys, Chr(10))
End Sub
```